# Defining volatile class object

Tags: c++, volatile

Can the volatile be used for class objects?
Like:

```
volatile Myclass className;
```

The problem is that it doesn't compile,
everywhere when some method is invoked, the error says:
error C2662: 'function' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'volatile MyClass' to 'MyCLass &'

What is the problem here and how to solve it?

EDIT:

```
class Queue {
            private:
                struct Data *data;
                int amount;
                int size;
            public:
                Queue ();
                ~Queue ();
                bool volatile push(struct Data element);
                bool volatile pop(struct Data *element);
                void volatile cleanUp();
            };
    .....
    volatile Queue dataIn;

        .....

    EnterCriticalSection(&CriticalSection);
    dataIn.push(element);
    LeaveCriticalSection(&CriticalSection);
```

Comment: Note that in C++, `volatile` does not guarantee thread-safety. That's different from, for example, .NET, where it does.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you can, but then you can only call member functions that are declared `volatile` (just like the `const` keyword). For example:

```
 struct foo {
    void a() volatile;
    void b();
 };

 volatile foo f;
 f.a(); // ok
 f.b(); // not ok
```

---

**Edit based on your code:**

```
bool volatile push(struct Data element);
```

declares a *non*-`volatile` member function that returns a `bool volatile` (= `volatile bool`). You want

```
bool push(struct Data element) volatile;
```

Comment: What about constructors and destructors and variables(properties) declared in class?

Comment: @maximus, constructors and destructors can't be overloaded with `volatile` (or `const`), and member variables inherit these properties from the class instance. Regarding your error messages, please post the exact code you're using.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now everything is ok!

Answer (score 7):

I think he meant to say

```
            bool push(struct Data element) volatile;
```

instead of

```
            bool volatile push(struct Data element);
```

Also have a look here http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13671

Answer (score 4):

In C++ grammar, "volatile" and "const" are called "CV modifiers". That means "volatile" works in exact the same way as "const" from syntactic point of view.
You can replace all "volatile" with "const" then you can understand why your code compiles or not.

Answer (score 3):

Yep. We can use. Please see the modified code.
I hope it should work now.

```
class Queue {
            private:
                struct Data *data;
                int amount;
                int size;
            public:
                Queue ();
                ~Queue ();
                bool push(struct Data element) volatile;
                bool pop(struct Data *element) volatile;
                void cleanUp() volatile;
            };
.....
volatile Queue dataIn;

    .....

EnterCriticalSection(&CriticalSection);
dataIn.push(element);
LeaveCriticalSection(&CriticalSection);
```